# Change radius of circle on distance change

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am implementing google map where user can set the distance(eg 10km or 15 km). Based on km distance circle/marker in map should change. [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (circle != null) circle.setRadius(0); return;
        double radius = 1000 * range;//range would be in meters
        if (circle != null) {
            circle.setCenter(mMap.getCameraPosition().target);
            circle.setRadius(radius);
        } else {
            circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(mMap.getCameraPosition().target)
                    .radius(radius)
                    .strokeWidth(5f)
                    .strokeColor(0x80ED1F29)
                    .fillColor(0x1A00B200));
        }
```

> Note: range= radius in meter and circle will be globle variable